# MySQL Query Slowed by Parameter Check on Joined Table

Tags: mysql

I am writing a stored procedure whose function is to take a number of parameters (populated by an end user) and perform a search. However, where a parameter has no value, it should not be included in the WHERE clause. For this I am carrying out a check on the parameter as the first part of an OR clause, like so:

```
... WHERE (param1 = '' OR field1 = param1) AND (param2 = '' OR field2 = param2)  ...
```

I have then incorporated this into a general select statement like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE (param1 = '' OR t1.field1 = param1)
```

***Please note** that I have only included one parameter in this example for clarity. The real query contains multiple parameters and field comparisons.*

This works fine and runs quickly (e.g. the 'real' query returns a result in approx 0.5 secs).

So far so good. However, when introduce a joined table, things start going wrong. For example if I execute the query below, it takes far longer (3-4 seconds on the real query):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1

LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.table2Id = t2.id

WHERE (param1 = '' OR t2.field1 = param1)
```

***Please note** that the parameter is now being compared to a field in the joined table (table2).*

***Please note** that in both of these examples, when running the query I have ensured that param1 is populated with a value.*

Now, if I remove the `param1 = '' OR` section of the above WHERE clause, it runs as quickly as the previous un-joined query.

None of the fields used in my tables are currently indexed although I have tried this and it made no difference to the problem I have.

So, could anyone explain to me why the first query (single table) works quickly but the second query (joined tables) takes disproportionately longer?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by removing the `LEFT JOIN` on table2 and replacing it with a simple `JOIN` as per below:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1

JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.table2Id = t2.id

WHERE (param1 = '' OR t2.field1 = param1)
```

To be honest, there was absolutely no reason for to have made this a LEFT JOIN. I just wasn't thinking! Anyway, many thanks to Evan and Michael for their help and advice (as well as their super quick responses).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the first condition as part of the `JOIN` and see if that helps you.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1

LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.table2Id = t2.id AND
t2.field1 = param1
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. I tried this as you have suggested, but now I get no results when param1 has a value.

Comment: Sorry Evan. Unfortunately now I cannot 'filter out' any parameters without a value.

Comment: Why not? You're saying you want results (both null and *not* null, so what's the point of the `where` ?

Comment: Sorry if I have not been clear Evan. The point of having the test for each parameter being equal to '' (i.e. no value) is so that the query will continue, even if the user has not provided a value for that parameter (the field it is being compared to in the database will always have a value). 

In other words, I only want to bring back results where the user has provided a value, and that value matches the appropriate field.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a view, and use the result from that view in your join statement.

```
CREATE VIEW `VW_my_simple_table_view_name` AS SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE (param1 = '' OR t1.field1 = param1)
```

and then the query would look something like this(might need adaptation)

```
SELECT *
FROM VW_my_simple_table_view_name t1

LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.table2Id = t2.id

WHERE (t2.field1 = param1)
```

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks for your suggestion, but I am not sure that approach will work. If you take a look at my joined table example, I am comparing the parameter to the field in table2. I am not actually comparing with any of table1's fields. Sorry if I missing your point somewhere!